# How to hide a div in the Repeater

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, vb.net

I have been working on VB ASP.NET site, Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web. I have a Repeater with two div tags and css classes .dnnFormLabel  and .dnnFormItem. Here is a part code in the Repeater:

```
<div class="dnnFormLabel dnnFormShort">
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSubQuestionBox" Text='<%#Eval("Label")%>' />
</div>
<div class="dnnFormItem dnnFormShort">
    <div>
        <label><span>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSubQuestionLabel" runat="server"><%#Eval("Prefix")%>&nbsp;<%#Eval("Label")%></asp:Label></span></label></div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ID="txtSubQuestionBox"></asp:TextBox>
    <%#Eval("description")%>
</div>
```

I want to hide div with class .dnnFormItem when it doesn't have any content. For this, I tried with:

```
.dnnFormItem:empty {
       display: none !important;
    }
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do this? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Your example has children in it that's why your css doesn't work. Also, why would you hide it if its empty? Its technically empty and won't  show anything.

Comment: Can you give some code please? I want to hide this div because I have a blank line between check boxes  in the first div with class dnnFormLabel.

Comment: how about `visible`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Panel` for that and set the `Visible` property based on a column value from the dataset.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="dnnFormItem dnnFormShort" Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("columnToValidate").ToString()) %>'>
    <div>
        <label>
            <span>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSubQuestionLabel" runat="server"><%#Eval("tocht_id")%>&nbsp;<%#Eval("naam_tocht")%></asp:Label></span></label>
    </div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ID="txtSubQuestionBox"></asp:TextBox>
    <%#Eval("naam_tocht")%>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

there should have nothing (include \n) inside div, such as:

```
<div class="dnnFormItem dnnFormShort"></div>
```

then .dnnFormItem:empty can tank effect.

```
<div class="dnnFormItem dnnFormShort">
</div>
```

will not work

Comment: thank you, but I need some code that will work :) Can you help pls?